# Opposite to CSS Reset. I Need Browser defaults for a div element

Tags: css

Just like css reset would remove all browser styling defaults, is there any css script that would bring back all browser defaults overriding parent css styles and classes just like an iframe?

Just like an iframe uses browser defaults if no source is used and if we inject simple html into it, I would like to impose browser defaults on to a div.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="10u two-col">
        <div class="col1">
          <div class= ??????>   ------> This div should have browser defaults just like an iframe.
            <h1> Hello World </h1>
            <ul>
              <li>point one</li>
              <li>point two</li>
              <li>point three</li>
            </ul>               
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure there is no standardised styling for ALL browsers, this is why we use reset.

Answer (score 7):

I dont believe there is an opposite for CSS reset type stylesheets (**Update:** because of this I [created one here](https://github.com/sw4/unreset.css)), but you can include the default styles used by the spec or a particular browser.

[See here for the default HTML4 stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html) (see [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html) for HTML5)

```
html, address,
blockquote,
body, dd, div,
dl, dt, fieldset, form,
frame, frameset,
h1, h2, h3, h4,
h5, h6, noframes,
ol, p, ul, center,
dir, hr, menu, pre   { display: block; unicode-bidi: embed }
li              { display: list-item }
head            { display: none }
table           { display: table }
tr              { display: table-row }
thead           { display: table-header-group }
tbody           { display: table-row-group }
tfoot           { display: table-footer-group }
col             { display: table-column }
colgroup        { display: table-column-group }
td, th          { display: table-cell }
caption         { display: table-caption }
th              { font-weight: bolder; text-align: center }
caption         { text-align: center }
body            { margin: 8px }
h1              { font-size: 2em; margin: .67em 0 }
h2              { font-size: 1.5em; margin: .75em 0 }
h3              { font-size: 1.17em; margin: .83em 0 }
h4, p,
blockquote, ul,
fieldset, form,
ol, dl, dir,
menu            { margin: 1.12em 0 }
h5              { font-size: .83em; margin: 1.5em 0 }
h6              { font-size: .75em; margin: 1.67em 0 }
h1, h2, h3, h4,
h5, h6, b,
strong          { font-weight: bolder }
blockquote      { margin-left: 40px; margin-right: 40px }
i, cite, em,
var, address    { font-style: italic }
pre, tt, code,
kbd, samp       { font-family: monospace }
pre             { white-space: pre }
button, textarea,
input, select   { display: inline-block }
big             { font-size: 1.17em }
small, sub, sup { font-size: .83em }
sub             { vertical-align: sub }
sup             { vertical-align: super }
table           { border-spacing: 2px; }
thead, tbody,
tfoot           { vertical-align: middle }
td, th, tr      { vertical-align: inherit }
s, strike, del  { text-decoration: line-through }
hr              { border: 1px inset }
ol, ul, dir,
menu, dd        { margin-left: 40px }
ol              { list-style-type: decimal }
ol ul, ul ol,
ul ul, ol ol    { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0 }
u, ins          { text-decoration: underline }
br:before       { content: "\A"; white-space: pre-line }
center          { text-align: center }
:link, :visited { text-decoration: underline }
:focus          { outline: thin dotted invert }

/* Begin bidirectionality settings (do not change) */
BDO[DIR="ltr"]  { direction: ltr; unicode-bidi: bidi-override }
BDO[DIR="rtl"]  { direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: bidi-override }

*[DIR="ltr"]    { direction: ltr; unicode-bidi: embed }
*[DIR="rtl"]    { direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: embed }

@media print {
  h1            { page-break-before: always }
  h1, h2, h3,
  h4, h5, h6    { page-break-after: avoid }
  ul, ol, dl    { page-break-before: avoid }
}
```

Or:

1. **[Firefox](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/html.css)**
2. **[Internet Explorer](http://www.iecss.com/)**
3. **[Chrome / Webkit](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css)**

nb: unable to paste in code, exceeds character limit

Comment: Thanks a lot, but could you tell me how can I assign all these styles to a class and use it simply like the yahoo css reset class?

Comment: Can you please explain me the usage? Like yahoo css reset class style. I am looking for a class that can be used to get browser defaults.

Comment: unreset.css (file) includes the default W3C HTML4 spec styling for elements, to use simply include unreset.css in the head of your page, then add the class 'unreset' to any element you wish to apply the default stylings to. When I have time I'll also fold in any browser specific styles.

Comment: Can you please give one browser specific reset class just like the unreset class you just gave me? lets say chrome. I will use the same for all. I am not having any issue using chrome defaults on other browsers for just this div element. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Actually as a matter of fact, I need an ID instead of class. So that I can give the ID to the DIV and and it will cascade within the div. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: @SW4, Weird, default font sizes are all in em. So where does all these ems base their reference on?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `all: initial`

Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all

Support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-all

Comment: This is incredible. I've written CSS for 2 decades now, and this is the first time I'm hearing about this.

Comment: @balu this property is "only" ten years old

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 'normalize.css' :

"Normalize.css makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. It precisely targets only the styles that need normalizing."

Link: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: The biggest problem, I have is assigning these styling to a class and using it. I am not a css pro. Is there a class that is readily available like normalize.css which can be used like yahoo css reset yui3-cssreset class?

Answer (score 0):

also something that can be installed through npm https://github.com/ixkaito/unreset.css gives the user a class called unreset to reset the styles within that specific element.